# Best way to send nlohmann json payload using cpr C++ Request library

Tags: c++

I'm trying to post JSON objects to the external server using two C++ libraries: [nlohmann/json](http://nlohmann.github.io/json) and [whoshuu/cpr](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr)

In python I can do this simply by using `requests.post(url, json=data)`

Is there a simple way to convert `nlohmann::json` class to `cpr::Payload` equivalent needed for `cpr::POST`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do like [this example from their documentation](http://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/introduction.html#post-requests):

```
auto r = cpr::Post(cpr::Url{"http://www.httpbin.org/post"},
                   cpr::Body{"This is raw POST data"},
                   cpr::Header{{"Content-Type", "text/plain"}});
```

Instead of using `cpr::Payload`, use `cpr::Body` and the [`dump()` method](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a805e3f3a2f374da0e14942eec7400e40.html#a805e3f3a2f374da0e14942eec7400e40) on the json object.